# Unable to write an encoded json Data object to a local file in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `data.json` file in the root of my Swift 5 project to which I would like to write some data. The file is already filled with data beforehand, but I would like to overwrite it.

This is the function I use to encode an array of `Task` structs into JSON Data:

```
func encode(task: Task){
    loadJSON()
    t.append(task)
    if let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(t){
        saveJSON(json: json)
    }
}
```

`loadJSON()` loads the JSON data into the `t` array from the `data.json` file, then the new `Task` is appended to the array, and then I create a `json` constant with encoded data from the `t` array, and call the `saveJSON` function.

```
func saveJSON(json: Data){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json"){
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do{
            try json.write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The path and the url are set, then the `do` is executed and it just falls through without doing anything. The `data.json` file is unchanged and `json.write` doesn't throw any errors.

I'm not entirely sure why am I unable to write to the file. I've tried to write a simple string instead of a data set, with similar results.

Comment: You can't write to the resource folder, it is read only - but you should be seeing an error explaining exactly that (something like: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “data.json”) Are you sure the json.write is executing? Set a breakpoint there to be sure.

Comment: @Dale I think it is executing, the program stops on a breakpoint with green "(lldb)" note in the console, and then executes as normal once I step over a few times. I didn't know that it's impossible to write into the resource folder, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by your attempting to write to the bundle directory, which cannot be written to directly (from all accounts, it seems).  Moving your file to a writable directory, like the user's documents directory, will allow you to modify or delete the file as you wish.

You can copy your resource file into the documents directory so it can be accessed locally, and made available to the user as well.  Here's an example helper method that copies a file (in your case, pass the string `data.json` as the `sourceFile` argument) from the Bundle into the documents directory:

```
func copyFileFromBundleToDocumentsFolder(sourceFile: String, destinationFile: String = "") {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

    if let documentsURL = documentsURL {
        let sourceURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(sourceFile)

        // Use the same filename if destination filename is not specified
        let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(!destinationFile.isEmpty ? destinationFile : sourceFile)

        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destURL)
            print("Removed existing file at destination")
        } catch (let error) {
            print(error)
        }

        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
            print("\(sourceFile) was copied successfully.")
        } catch (let error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

After doing that -- if you need to make modifications to the newly created file, you can create another function that overwrites the file with your specific json data using almost exactly the same logic.

You can adapt your loadJSON() and saveJSON() functions to read from or write to this new file (inside the document directory).  For saving, something like this:

```
func saveJSONDataToFile(json: Data, fileName: String) {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

    if let documentsURL = documentsURL {
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        do {
            try json.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomicWrite)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Changes to the Document Directory should persist.  Here is code to retrieve the list of all files in that directory.  It should help to check that the file in question is being persisted properly:

```
func listDocumentDirectoryFiles() {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

    if let url = documentsURL {
        do {
            let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: url.path)
            print("\(contents.count) files inside the document directory:")
            for file in contents {
                print(file)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not retrieve contents of the document directory.")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.  Feel free to ask in the comments if anything is unclear.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have adjusted my code so that now it reads/writes from/to the Document Directory instead of Bundle. I have also used your code to copy the json file from the Bundle to the Document Directory. The thing is when I comment out the call of your function and recompile the app, the data is no longer there, as if I never copied it. Isn't data in the Document Directory supposed to be persistent? Or is it a problem with the fact I'm using a Simulator and not a real iPhone?

Comment: The data in the Document Directory should be persistent.  I tried a similar test, and just reading the file out on a subsequent app launch (on a simulator), confirmed that the file that was written previously, was still there.  I'll add a function that lists  the files in the directory.  Hopefully it will help you to debug your issue.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I've modified your function a bit to show me the contents of the data.json file as well, so that it's easier for me to see in real time what exactly is my program writing in there and now I see exactly how that works. The problem was that while the data was persistent, the app was writing data that wasn't exactly compliant with the model, that's why it wouldn't show up in my app.